# Add multiple duration terms in application.yml for single property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

In Spring Boot it's possible do set a configuration variable in application.yml as follows:

```
myprogram:
   my-property: 5d # respectively 5 days
```

And in code it can be retrieved like that:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("myprogram")
public class MyProgramProperties {

    @DurationUnit(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
    private Duration myProperty = Duration.ofSeconds(30); // default = 30 sec, if config var is not set

    public Duration getMyProperty() {
        return this.myProperty ;
    }

    public void setMyProperty(Duration myProperty ) {
        this.myProperty = myProperty ;
    }

}
```

But is it possible to have the following and if so how to achieve this:

```
myprogram:
   my-property: 5d 3h 5m # respectively 5 days, 3 hours, 5 minutes
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so, you'll need to treat it as String and have separate get methods to extract what you want.

Comment: I've implemented my own DurationParser like Atlassian Jira does.